# Joining three tables together to get three values from each

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join three tables together but keep getting the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INNER JOIN ts_building.id=ts_room.building_id INNER JOIN
>   ts_park.id=ts_build' at line 2: SELECT
>   ts_room.building_id,ts_building.park,ts_park INNER JOIN
>   ts_building.id=ts_room.building_id INNER JOIN
>   ts_park.id=ts_building.park_id WHERE ts_room.id="CC.0.21"

What I am I doing wrong? Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT ts_room.building_id,ts_building.park,ts_park
    INNER JOIN ts_building.id=ts_room.building_id
    INNER JOIN ts_park.id=ts_building.park_id
WHERE ts_room.id="CC.0.21"
```

I've uploaded the SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecaa6/2

Comment: I don't see a `FROM` clause

Comment: Tip: break down the SQL when you get syntax errors. Makes it easier to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Syntax is

```
select ts_room.building_id,ts_park.park
from ts_room
inner join ts_building on ts_building.id=ts_room.building_id
inner join ts_park on ts_park.id=ts_building.park_id
where ts_room.id="CC.0.21"
```

You where missing the from clause and the table which to join

General Syntax is more or less:

```
Select <columns>
from <table1>
[inner|outer|left|right] join <table2> on <condition>
[inner|outer|left|right] join <table3> on <condition>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `FROM` clause, also on your `INNER JOIN` you need to specify `ON`, the query should look like:

```
SELECT ts_room.building_id,ts_building.park,ts_park
FROM ts_room
INNER JOIN ts_building ON ts_building.id = ts_room.building_id
INNER JOIN ts_park ON tsPpark.id = ts_building.park_id
WHERE ts_room.id="CC.0.21"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Don't you need the table name after the join and then the `on` condition?

Comment: @Hyperboreus indeed you do, good spot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify Table Names after `From` and `INNER JOIN` clauses

```
SELECT *
FROM ts_room
    INNER JOIN ts_building ON ts_building.id=ts_room.building_id
    INNER JOIN ts_park ON ts_park.id=ts_building.park_id
WHERE ts_room.id="CC.0.21"
```

NOTE : There is no `ts_building.park`, `ts_park` fields in the tables (as in your original query), so I selected all (*)